# Magento 2 : What is <bulk_size> and <direct_document_copy> element in data migration tool config file?

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

In data migration tool config file we have`<bulk_size>` and `<direct_document_copy>` elements. What values are expected for these tags and what are their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## bulk_size

It is the amount of data processed at one time.

Set bulk_size as `0` and it will be auto-detected for every document. It is **better** than set bulk_size as a fixed value.

## direct_document_copy

Default value is `0`, set it as `1` for better performance.

Set direct_document_copy as `1` will direct copy data from database, but 'source' and 'destination' databases **MUST** be placed on **the same MySQL instance** and 'destination' user MUST be granted with **'SELECT' permissions** on 'source' database.

Comment: auto-detected for every document. What is it mean ?
Can you please explain ?

Comment: @Aji It means the value is decided by the migration module codes. How it works and decide value you need to study its codes, I don't spend much time on the auto-detected  value, because there is __a lot of other migration works__ to do. I just set `bulk_size` as `0` and it works well. Migration is a big deal, we don’t need to make every principle clear when using tools, that's a terrible workload. If anyone has time to study the codes, could add a new answer here :)